# Why Deployment Descriptor: Archetype Created Web Application, appears in every packages in SpringMVC maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller

When I create my very first spring mvc with maven project, Deployment descriptor: Archetype Create Web Application is containing under every package. I can't delete it. How to resolve it.

I try many solutions by googling. I can't even find one solution. It is strange.